# What is the cheapest available freighter voyage anywhere?

Tags: budget, freighter-travel, where-on-earth

Walking past a huge international shipyard twice today got me thinking about [freighter travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Freighter_travel). We have a couple of such questions on the site, but not many.

Many people are surprised when they find out that freighter travel is often more expensive than flying and I just looked at the website of the Australian company "Freighter Expeditions" and found most of the trips listed even more expensive than I was expecting.

But this surely isn't the only company / website dealing in freighter travel - I just don't know where else to look?

My question is **"What is the cheapest freighter travel trip available anywhere in the world?"**

Comment: I presume that you mean as a passenger.

Comment: @mouviciel: I mean as a traveller, so yes (-:

Comment: I don't know if they are the cheapest, but  http://www.cargoshipcruises.nl/english.htm publishes their fares online

Comment: What if it's like...from Portsmouth to Southhampton or something?

Comment: @MarkMayo: It would be disappointing but at least we'd know. For now I'm still under the impression that everything is in the thousands of dollars. Info is hard to come by. Long tail and all that stuff (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Can you define "freighter" and minimum length of "voyage" for the purpose of this question?  Eg. many outlying islands in Japan are reachable only by all-purpose cargo boat that carry both freight and passengers.

Comment: @jpatokal: No not really. I didn't even know it was generally called "freighter travel" until it came up on this site. I would regard it, no matter which name it is called, to be travelling on a boat/ship whose primary function is to carry cargo/freight. If a boat/ship is normally understood to carry both cargo and passengers then I wouldn't regard that as "freighter travel". Perhaps there's a better name than that but that's what the spirit of these questions is, whatever we call it.

Comment: Terminology varies but 12 passengers is [a common threshold](http://www.imo.org/OurWork/Safety/Regulations/Pages/PassengerShips.aspx). Ships with mixed passenger/cargo service are often called “mail ships”. There are some to [St. Helena](http://rms-st-helena.com/), [Pitcairn](http://www.visitpitcairn.pn/visitpitcairn/shipping/), [French Polynesia](http://www.aranui.com/), [Antarctica](http://www.taaf.fr/-Le-Marion-Dufresne-) and minor outlying islands everywhere. The [Hurtigruten](http://www.hurtigruten.com/) is/was another one, although newer ships seems increasingly focused on tourism.

Comment: But those are typically passenger ships that happen to have space for cargo, not that different from a Baltic or Med ferry and sometimes even with cruise ship-level accommodation and service. Pure freighters by contrast typically depart from some hard-to-reach part of industrial ports, require a medical certificate and specific insurance, can't be booked with a credit card on the web, etc.

Comment: @user141: That page is a 404, but their home page has an "English" link.  Looks like their prices are more than US$100 per day.  I've read in a couple of places to estimate $50 per day.  New York to London on Cunard, balcony cabin, seven days for $800.  (not cargo ship)

Comment: It does appear more expensive but the number of days with full board and travel including the experience......is it really?.
It is not for everyone as you need to take all your entertainment with you. Container ships are working ships so they are not there to entertain you.
I did a 10 weeks trip and was the only passenger, I enjoyed the peace but its not for everyone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been wondering about that as well and here is what I could find.

I read about trips with several major container ship operators (CMA-CGM, Hanjin Shipping, MSC, NSB) plus some roros and Polish bulkers. I also found many agencies selling more-or-less the same trips (a few in Germany, one each in France, the US, Australia and the UK). In all cases, the prices were around EUR 80-110 per day, plus deviation insurance and embarkation fees (which are more-or-less fixed costs, so they weigh much more heavily on short journeys).

Those are the only companies I have heard of that verifiably take passengers on a regular basis and they all have pretty similar prices/conditions. Thus any trip across the Atlantic or Pacific, to or from Asia or Oceania or through the Suez canal will cost at least €2000-3000, sometimes much more and circumnavigations start at €10,000.

Consequently, it seems the price does not depend so much on the ship, the agency or the operator but mostly on the route/length of the voyage. At EUR 100 per day, ocean crossings or longer journeys will always cost a few thousands euros/dollars. Voyages to or from Australia and New Zealand also seem in particularly high demand.

The only other option seems to be shorter “partial” journeys, hopping on and off a ship doing a longer rotation. Nothing dirt cheap and certainly nothing cheaper than a commercial flight but still some opportunities to travel on a freighter for less than EUR 900/USD 1000. Some examples:

- Partial journeys on [Grimaldi Lines' “Euromed” roro tours](http://www.grimaldi-freightercruises.com/freighter/italia/medItaliano.pdf), for example Salerno (Italy) to Setubal (in Portugal) or Salerno to Limassol (Cyprus) or Ashdod (Israel). Salerno-Setubal is €285 per person in an internal cabin with a double bed or €315 in a cabin with three single beds (but I think you have to find your travel companions yourself and book the entire cabin together, unlike couchettes on trains). That's the absolute cheapest price I came across. Some agencies also list the Italy-Cyprus trip, usually with a small markup.
- Rotterdam-UK and return (no one-way journey) on a container ship, €345 per person through [Kapitän Zylmann](http://zylmann.de/index.php?id=40&no_cache=1&tx_ticzylmannpassage_pi1%5Bdetail%5D=950) (price includes insurance and admin fees). Kapitän Zylmann offers another round trip, [Portugal to Morocco and back](http://zylmann.de/index.php?id=40&no_cache=1&tx_ticzylmannpassage_pi1%5Bdetail%5D=945) on a small container ship, for €560. According to the website, it only calls at one port in Morocco where the whole cargo is unloaded so it stays longer than usual in that port, which should allow passengers to disembark and explore a bit before returning to Portugal.
- Rotterdam-Dublin-Rotterdam through [Frachtschiffreisen Pfeiffer](http://frachtschiffreisen-pfeiffer.de/104a-irland/), starting at €490, two days at port in Dublin, apparently no one-way crossing available but it should be possible to go on land. The same agency has a number of [one-week trips to the British Isles or across the Baltic](http://frachtschiffreisen-pfeiffer.de/reisen/reisen-nach-dauer/1-woechige-reisen/) also around €500-600.
- Fos-sur-Mer (near Marseille) to Malta, with a container ship from CMA-CGM. Listed by [Mer & voyages](http://www.mer-et-voyages.info/voyages_en_cargo.php?ville=Pays%2C+Ville%2C+Compagnie&nb_jours=5&prix_max=prix+max&base=2&ref_produit=) as “Med 1287” for €570 (but that does not include insurance and admin fees). It might also [be bookable directly from the ship's operator](http://www.cityzeum.com/ar/voyager-en-cargo), possibly a bit cheaper. If I am not mistaken, the ships on that line continue to Suez and then Asia. CMA CGM operates some of the largest container ships in the world and they are much larger than the ships listed above so it might be a good way to experience what modern shipping is like.
- Cartagena to Guayaquil, over the Panama canal, is listed for €800 by [Kapitän Zylmann](http://zylmann.de/index.php?id=40&no_cache=1&tx_ticzylmannpassage_pi1%5Bdetail%5D=859). From the same agency, it's apparently possible to book [Cartagena to Puerto Cabello](http://zylmann.de/index.php?id=40&no_cache=1&tx_ticzylmannpassage_pi1%5Bdetail%5D=884) in Venezuela for €610 including fees and insurance. In the same region, [NSB sells journeys on container ships](http://www.nsb-reisebuero.de/de/meine-frachtschiffreise/routenliste/?tx_rsnsb_route%5BinRoute%5D=27&tx_rsnsb_route%5Baction%5D=list&tx_rsnsb_route%5Bcontroller%5D=Route&cHash=3d77ea134d5a8309cb5759dc604527ba) taking passengers and calling at Cartagena, Port-of-Spain, Kingston, Manaus, etc. They don't list many details on price or conditions but it might possible to create some interesting shorter journeys from those lines.
- Antwerpen-Istanbul with a container ship from MSC, also [bookable through Pfeiffer](http://frachtschiffreisen-pfeiffer.de/163-nordeuropa-tuerkei/). A bit more expensive at €810 plus fees and insurance (in total EUR 1100/USD 1250/AUD 1600), but still close to €1000 and a meaningful journey, crossing Gibraltar and the Mediterranean, 9 days (only double beds so here again travelling alone is more expensive). Slightly cheaper but following a similar idea, it's possible to go from [Hamburg to Genoa](http://frachtschiffe.eu/?page_id=1811) for €785.

From what I can tell, some agencies are a little more reluctant to sell short trips than others but it seems that it's often possible to book a partial journey on a given freighter line. So you could also check the longer journeys on all the websites listed here and then approach an agency to enquire about a specific trip, even it's not listed explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a freigther, but if you consider a yacht also a valuable way of sea transport, you can get some valuable advice at: http://wikitravel.org/en/Hitchhiking_boats
. On this nice reading article, I found a link to http://www.findacrew.net.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Andra, but for this question I was specifically hoping to get some hard info about freighter experiences.

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifically looking for freighter ships, or will any ship do? Cruises from certain cities during certain parts of the year can be incredibly cheap — often cheaper than flying, if you go with another person. [CruiseSheet](http://cruisesheet.com/) is a good way to find these, though keep in mind that the prices are per-person and that you also need to factor in taxes (usually not too bad) and tips (something like $12-$15 a day). It might not be as romantic as heading out into the unknown on a rusty cargo bucket, but it's darn comfortable and they feed you really well!

Comment: This question was specifically about travelling on cargo ships, since such info is harder to come by and many people seem to expect it must be cheap, but it isn't really.