# How to hitchhike on a cargo ship from India to say somewhere like Africa or Mediterranean?

Tags: sailing, freighter-travel

How to hitchhike on a cargo ship from India to say somewhere like Africa or Mediterranean? What will be the requirements and cost to travel alone? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Hitchhiking is by definition something you do on a road. It's not clear what you mean in connection with a ship. Do you mean to stow away, traveling without the knowledge if the ship's crew? Or do you intend to arrange for your passage legally? In the latter case, you're not hitchhiking, you're simply a paying passenger.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43840/how-can-i-get-to-iceland-on-a-cargo-ship

Comment: I think "hitchhiking on a ship" means traveling with the full knowledge and consent of the ship's crew, but for free, e.g. through befriending the captain/crew (or in exchange for doing some chores around the ship). I've personally spoken to at least 2 people who have successfully done so, but from what I hear it's becoming more and more difficult / near impossible due to insurance reasons (but may still be possible on some internal routes within one country like Russia or Indonesia, or with smaller/independent shipping operators, or just with a captain willing to bend the rules).

Comment: By the way, there's also "hitchhiking on trains", which from what I hear is not all that rare in Russia, especially the more remote regions (befriend locomotive engineer of a freight train, ride for free in the locomotive), I've seen detailed guides on how to best do this and have spoken to people who have done this, so hitchhiking definitely isn't limited to just the road...

Comment: I meant travelling with full knowledge and consent of the ship crew and others. It does not really have to be free and I can do chores for sure, but cheap will be good enough for someone like me. That's why I asked about cargo vessels. What about the laws that will be applicable on a "hitchhiker" like that? Can I just go down the ship with passport when in some other country?

Comment: I am prepared to pay, but not much as I can't. What are the legal bindings that can be applied to this thought?

Comment: Since the questioner is still around, I will add here that according to Wikitravel, it has not been possible to hitchhike/stow away on freighters since around the 1970s. There are probably serious legal issues involved. The freighter cruise is the only option.